# Command to DM the mentioned users

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Here's my code to DM the mentioned members.

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "dm",
  category: "moderation",
  usage: "DM <@mention> <message>",
  description: "DM server members!",
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) {
      return message.channel.send(
        "Access restricted!"
      );
    }

    const targets = message.mentions.members;

    if (!targets) {
      return message.channel.send(
        "Please Mention the person to who you want to DM!"
      );
    }

    if (message.mentions.users.bot) {
      return message.channel.send("You cannot DM bots");
    }

    const reason = args.slice(0).join(" ");

    if (!reason) {
      return message.channel.send(
        "Place provide the message to send!"
      );
    }

    message.channel.send(`DM sent succesfully!`);
      
      let embed = new MessageEmbed()
.setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle(`Message from ${message.guild.name}`)
    .setDescription(`${reason}`)
    .setThumbnail('https://i.ibb.co/PCnBZ8w/IMG-20210205-191207.jpg')
    .setFooter(`Sent by ${message.member.user.tag}`)
    
      targets.forEach(target => target.send(embed));
      message.delete();
  }
};
```

It is used like so: `prefixdm the message @mention1 @mention2 ...`.
But in the DM received by the users they also get the mentions of the command due my declaration of `reason`. How can I fix it so that they don't see the mentions in the message?

Answer (score 0):

You can clean up the message using regex. `MessageMentions` has a [`USERS_PATTERN`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=s-USERS_PATTERN) property that contains the regular expression that matches the user mentions (like `<@82043902196179341>`). You can use it with JavaScript's [`.replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) method to replace all occurrences of the mention with an empty string:

```js
const reason = args
  .slice(0)
  .join(' ')
  .replaceAll(MessageMentions.USERS_PATTERN, '')
  .trim();
```

Don't forget to import `MessageMentions` from `discord.js`:

```js
const { MessageEmbed, MessageMentions } = require("discord.js");
```

**Update:** You can also use `.replace()` instead of `.replaceAll()` as the regex globally matches user mentions. [Source](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/stable/src/structures/MessageMentions.js#L211).

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am unable figure how to replaceALL the mentions.

Comment: Why? I've already provided the code above, it replaces every mentioned user with an empty string.

Comment: .replaceAll is not a function

Comment: It's only available in Node.js v15+. What's your node version? Type `node -v` in terminal

Comment: @Anush You can also use `.replace()` instead of `.replaceAll()`.

Comment: Its .replace in V12